# Objective-C string wrapped in parentheses?

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm getting this on console.log;

```
2014-08-13 11:55:11.877 Wevo[14264:1830541] artist name: (
"Vance Joy"
)
```

How do I unwrap it so its just the string?

The problem comes because I'm parsing json that looks like this:

```
output =         {
        contributor =             {
            "/music/recording/artist" =                 [
                                    {
                    mid = "/m/026hdj4";
                    name = "Marie-Mai";
                }
            ];
        };
    };
```

notice how the mid is wrapped in an array?
So it gets converted to an object literal somewhere

I'm setting the value using:

```
_artistName = [[attributes[@"output"][@"contributor"][@"/music/recording/artist"] valueForKeyPath:@"name"] copy];
```

Comment: The object you call "artist name" in the dump is an NSArray (very easily identified because it's bracketed by `()`).  You're getting an array because you use valueForKeyPath and it returns an array if the referenced object is an array (which "/music/recording/artist" is, as can be seen by the JSON `[]` bracket characters).

Comment: (As a general rule, when you don't quite understand what you're doing, avoid "long chain polymer" operations such as `attributes[@"output"][@"contributor"][@"/music/recording/artist"]` and instead do each step separately, assigning the result to a temp.  This is much easier to debug, and easier to understand and maintain as well.  And it *is not* any less efficient than the one-liner.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `valueForKeyPath:`? If you use

```
_artistName = attributes[@"output"][@"contributor"][@"/music/recording/artist"][0][@"name"];
```

it should come out correctly.

**Edit**: For future viewers, one off lines like this will work. However, for a more maintainable and debuggable app, I would recommend splitting up the lines to extract only one object per line. That way, if something breaks, the debugger will be a larger help.

For apps where you deal with more JSON than just a one off, I would recommend creating model objects and pulling your JSON into those. There are libraries on github that could also help you there with model objects.

Comment: While this works, it is horrible (the fault of the OP). Break this up into separate lines. The code will be more readable and debuggable. :)

Comment: because I'm still learning and did not realize I could just access it like that! Thanks a bunch I'll mark this correct when the time limit is up